# Is it possible that ipywidget does not display figures on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I tried to use ipywidget on jupyter notebook in two enviroments, but a figure couldn't be displayed in one of the enviroments.

code is below;

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import interact

xs=np.linspace(0, 6, 100)

fig = go.FigureWidget()
fig.add_scatter()

@interact(a=(1.0, 4.0, 0.01), b=(0, 10.0, 0.01), color=['red', 'green', 'blue'])
def update(a=3.6, b=4.3, color='blue'):
    with fig.batch_update():
        fig.data[0].x=xs
        fig.data[0].y=np.sin(a*xs-b)
        fig.data[0].line.color=color
fig
```

### Normal operating environment(displays two sliders, one box, and a figure.);

- Python 3.6.8
- ipywidgets 7.5.1
- plotly 4.5.4
- jupyter notebook 6.0.3

### Abnormal operating environment(displays only two sliders and one box.);

- Python 3.7.6
- ipywidgets 7.5.1
- plotly 4.5.4
- jupyter notebook 6.0.2

What are the possibilities in this situation about this problem?
Is there any other information needed to solve it?